# How to return an json object when request is OK, and a json error object when failing in SpringBoot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, serialization

I have a method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Commande", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String authorizeMeter(...){
    try {
        MyObject result = port.commanderCollectePublicationMesures(demande);
    } catch (Erreur erreur) {
        return erreur;
    }
}
```

When the request is successful, I will get a MyObject result, and when I catch an error, and Erreur Object.

In the end, both of the response will be serialized, so, it will all be JSON.

This is if I put: `String` return type, compiler doesn't like it saying, I must return MyObject Type, or Erreur Type

If I have only 1 type ( MyObject ), Springboot will automatically serialize it to JSON which is great.

But how should I manage Erreur message?

Should I always convert myself the object into JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `ResponseEntity` as return type (org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity)

and the return statement should be

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(result)
```

or

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(erreur)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Yogesh Prajapati](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62590867/5558072) answer is correct. But in the error case, I would like to use another status codes, because `ResponseEntity.ok(..)` return 200 status code which is not good in case of an error, to solve this with an elegant solution you can use :

```
return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(error);
```

or by using other `HttpStatus` you can call this :

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(error);
```